# Common PHP/MySql login/registration file with validation

Tags: php, mysql, forms, validation, server-side

I am working on a website which will register and login users (using PHP and MySql). I'v got the html form done (with javascript validation) and insert_users php file done. There is so much else which needs to be done, like server-side validation, session ID, session hijacks, etc. Why am i reinventing the wheel when this has been done so many times before?
I'v been Googling this, but all i can find is sporadic tutorials on how to do small stuff. Any ideas where i can get a plug-n-play file or tutorial that does all of this for me?

Thanx guys.

David

Answer (score 1):

If everyone used the exact same auth system, then if a hacker compromises it the entire Internet is vulnerable. It's better to make your own - it may not be the most secure, but if it's different it would take a different hacking method to crack.